# C# - Need to Psuedo Click a Window

Tags: c#, click, bots

Well, first off, what I'm trying to do is click a specific point inside a flash object, inside of a webbrowser control. I'm not sure why it isn't working, but I cannot seem to click any window, be it notepad, or the actual program.

Here is my code that I'm using.

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle, IntPtr childAfter, string className, IntPtr windowTitle);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(String sClassName, String sAppName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public IntPtr find()
    {
        return this.Handle;//FindWindow("", "Form1");
    }

    public enum WMessages : int
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201, //Left mousebutton down
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x202,   //Left mousebutton up
        WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x203, //Left mousebutton doubleclick
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x204, //Right mousebutton down
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x205,   //Right mousebutton up
        WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x206, //Right mousebutton do
    }

    private int MAKELPARAM(int p, int p_2)
    {
        return ((p_2 << 16) | (p & 0xFFFF));
    }

    /** This is the non-working code **/
    public void DoMouseLeftClick(IntPtr handle, Point x)
    {
        SendMessage(handle, (int)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MAKELPARAM(x.X, x.Y));
        SendMessage(handle, (int)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(x.X, x.Y));

        return;

        //I have tried PostMessage, and SendMessage, and both of them at the same time, and neither works.

        PostMessage(handle, (uint)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, 0, MAKELPARAM(x.X, x.Y));
        PostMessage(handle, (uint)WMessages.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, MAKELPARAM(x.X, x.Y));
    }


    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //I try hovering my mouse over a button I added to the form, and nothing happens.
        DoMouseLeftClick(find(), Cursor.Position);
    }
```

So, I have tried using PostMessage, and SendMessage, and neither of those seem to work.
All I need it to do is to click on a specific point.

Also, I need to mention that I can't use mouse_event, because from what I know, the window needs to be active, plus the cursor needs to be over the point you are clicking. I am making a bot that automatically does a process in a flash object, so that's why I can't use mouse_event.

Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

I tried to draw something in the MS Paint. It turned out that I was clicking on the main window but it turned out that MS Paint (and most of the applications) consist of many child windows and you actually want to click on the child. So I had to change my code from:

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Paint");
PostMessage(handle, (uint)MOUSE_BUTTONS.LEFT_DOWN, 0, lparam);
```

to

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindow(null, "Untitled - Paint");
handle = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "MSPaintView", null);
canvasHandle = FindWindowEx(handle, IntPtr.Zero, "Afx:00007FF676DD0000:8", null);
PostMessage(canvasHandle, (uint)MOUSE_BUTTONS.LEFT_DOWN, 0, lparam);
```

You need to use tools like Spy++ for Windows that comes with C++ Visual Studio package if you want to debug these kind of things (even if you program in C#)

Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

For the `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, you may need to specify which button. Take reference for: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645607(v=vs.85).aspx

I used:

```
SendMessage(hWnd, (int)WMessages.WM_RBUTTONDOWN, (int)KeyDownMessage.MK_LBUTTON, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
```